# Vuetify list : open group according to active route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

Let's suppose I have a Vuetify list with 2 v-list-group, each one containing a v-list-tile. Here is a simplified pseudo-code:

```
 - Group1
   - Item 1 :to='/item1'
 - Group2
   - Item 2 :to='/item2'
```

My list works fine : if I click on "Item1", vue-router goes to "/item1".

Conversely, when I go to some route '/item1' (by typing the URL for example) and Group1 is closed in the list, is it possible to make Group1 to automatically open in the list?

Do I have to watch route and use v-list-group.value to set the open group, or does Vuetify have something to do this automatically?

Comment: Are you using Vue Router? And is `/item1` a route that's going to be handled by Vue Router?

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned I'm using vue-router

Comment: Instead of having routes that are watched, have you though of adding props to your route? (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) If so, and that's not suitable, then yes, watching your route would seen like the logical choice.

Comment: @chisnall.io I don't understand how route props can solve my problem. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using route watch : https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-router-template-0176-vy766 (based on Daniel's code).

The insteresting part is in Nav.vue:`

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    if (to.matched.length > 1) {
      const parent = to.matched.filter(m => !m.parent)[0];
      const route = routes.filter(route => route.name === parent.name)[0];
      route.active = true;
    }
  }
}
```