# Expand Vuetify list-group based on router props

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

In my navigation, I have a [list-group](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups#list-item-groups) where I am showing a list of locations.

My route looks like this:

```
{
    path: "/location/:id",
    name: "location.show",
    component: () =>
        import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "location.show" */ "../views/admin/location/Show"
            ),
    meta: {requiresAuth: true},
    props(route) {
        console.log('route:', route.params);
        const props = {...route.params};
        props.id = +props.id;
        return props;
    },
},
...
```

My template looks like this:

```
<v-list-group
    no-action
    prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-multiple"
    :value="false">
    <template v-slot:activator>
        <v-list-item-title>Locations</v-list-item-title>
    </template>
    <v-list-item
        v-for="location in locations"
        :key="location.id"
        :to="{ name: 'location.show', params: {id: location.id}}"
    link>
    <v-list-item-title>{{ location.name }}</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-map-marker</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-action>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list-group>
```

I know I need to set `:value="false"` to `:value="true"` to expand the group. Everything is working great - my group item(s) are being selected/highlighted correctly.

I believe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821172/vuetify-list-open-group-according-to-active-route) is talking about the same issue, I am really struggling to understand what is happening.

If a route matches `/location/<id>` I want my "Locations" group to be expanded. This would mean setting `:value="true"`. If I navigate away, I want to set `:value="false"`. I also have a route that looks like `/location/<id>/foo` so I know I can't explicitly match `/location/<id>`.

How can I set the value of `:value` based on the current route? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: you should watch your routes every time it changes and make a condition on it if it matched your url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making this way more complicated than it needed to be. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
...
data: () => ({
    expand_locations: false,
}),
watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
        this.expand_locations = to.path.includes("/location/");
    },
},
...
```

Then in my template:

```
<v-list-group
    no-action
    prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-multiple"
    :value="expand_locations">

    ...
```

Comment: Yep. Your comment helped; I wasn't sure what I was looking for. So chasing down the watcher - I set up data model to take the value if the route matched what I needed. The list-group expands/contracts as needed. 

I do feel like this might be a bit "hacky" and I'm sure as my page grows I will run into issues. For now, this gets me to ship faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

List groups now contain a prop called `group` which takes in either a string or a regex to "assign route namespace", see the [Vuetify Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/#props). Therefore your template could look something like this:

```
<v-list-group
    no-action
    prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-multiple"
    :group="location">
    ...
```

Comment: It looks like in V3 group prop is gone :( https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-group/#props